# FORMAT SQL function not available in databricks for number formatting

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark-sql, databricks

select a = FORMAT(Amount * Currency, 'F2', 'en-US') from schema.table

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'FORMAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 18 pos 37

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'FORMAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 18 pos 37

I'm trying to fetch data from SQL server and above is working fine in SSMS but not in Azure databricks.
Can any one help with the alternate databricks function or how to import FORMAT function in Databricks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `FORMAT` is a SQL Server function that doesn't exist in Spark SQL

Comment: Honestly, even if you are using SQL Server, I would recommend against `FORMAT`; it's a slow function. If you need *format* your values, do so in your presentation layer.